# Math operation on a string with a dollar sign ($) at the beginning

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a very simple percentage multiplication of a price that I am taking from a label. What I have so far is very simple:

```
private void richText10_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e) 
{
    string label7 = System.Convert.ToString(rptLabelForm.GetCurrentColumnValue("line_selling_price"));
    decimal percentage = 80;
    decimal price = System.Convert.ToDecimal(label7);
    decimal total = price * (percentage / 100);
    richText10.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run the report with live data I get an error saying

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I suspect that this is because the string I am trying to use is a double with a dollar sign at the beginning. (The label does show up with a dollar sign if I run it by itself.)

How can I solve this? How can I remove the dollar sign from the string in order to do that simple math equation? Is that even the reason for the error I am getting?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: In addition to the currency symbol, the decimal character will throw the same error when you try to convert the string to an integer type.

Comment: Note that with `long` (80/100) will be 0.  You want to use a type that can handle decimals and since you're dealing with money I'd suggest the `decimal` type.

Comment: OK so definitely use decimal then. I tried doing it that way but still got the same mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parse functions allow you to ignore currency symbols. This way you don't have to worry about String.Replace for every currency symbol.

```cs
var price = Decimal.Parse(label7, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number);
```

Also using the `long` datatype is probably not recommended when using monetary values. How about changing your code to this?

```cs
private void richText10_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    var label7 = System.Convert.ToString(rptLabelForm.GetCurrentColumnValue("line_selling_price"));
    var percentage = 80M;
    var price = Decimal.Parse(label7, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number);
    var total = price * (percentage / 100M);
    richText10.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @RickyDiaz if this answer solved your problem please mark it as the answer for future users who encounter the same problem